# Implementing Web Services timer for Tweet Service

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc

My problem is that I have a function implemented on my website which searches for Particular Tweet when I press the button. I want it to make it automatic such that, that function is called again and again after every two minutes, regardless some one uses the website or not.. How to do this in java?? Spring Solution is better

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring scheduling (see [documentation here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html))

From the doc:

### XML config

```
<context:component-scan base-package="some.package" />
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>
```

### Java bean

```
@Component
public class SomeBean {
    @Scheduled(fixedRate=5000)
    public void doSomething() {
        // something that should execute periodically
    }
}
```